# Mandatory Break clause

Tags: interest-rate-swap

Regarding mandatory break clause on Interest rate swaps can someone explain how pricing works with an example. Is it compulsory to terminate the swap or novate on the exercise date.  I have seen cases where the break dates are rolled forward prior to the exercise date.. Is this allowed

Comment: related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19440/how-do-right-to-break-clauses-affect-cva-calculations

Answer (score 2):

On the specific question being asked :  if there is a mandatory break in a swap, either counterparty can insist on exercising it.  Meaning, the swap gets torn up and its value determined using whatever methodology is in the confirmation.  However, because it is governed by a bilateral agreement, the swap can be altered by mutual consent at any time.   For example , the counterparties may agree to cancel or delay the mandatory break.